# Firebase OAuth popup not displaying on iPhone

Tags: iphone, safari, firebase

My application ( https://app.sketchdeck.com ) makes this call:

```
Firebase.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, onComplete, [options])
```

(api doc: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthpopup.html)

On desktop safari, it works great. On mobile safari, onComplete never gets called.

Any ideas for making it work on Safari mobile, or debugging further?

Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine popups aren't allowed on mobile Safari. Have you tried using authWithOAuthRedirect()? What errors are being reported? See here for an example of doing a redirect fallback: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-user-authentication

Comment: Thanks Kato! Going to try sniffing them out and trying that on them. I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: Ah - the Firebase JS api only has an onComplete callback, and on the IOS Safari instance it _never_ gets called, so its impossible to fallback. @Kato ideas?

Comment: Redirect does not trigger the callback (because it redirects). Do popup and fall back to redirect.

Comment: Hi, I've tried running WithOAuthRedirect, and on safari nothing happens (e.g. no new tab appears). Any ideas? Are there any good examples of Firebase google oauth working on mobile? Thanks

Comment: Redirect wouldn't open a new tab, it would redirect the current window. What's in the error log?